# Passing array from JSP to Javascript(how to create a matrix in javascript)

Tags: javascript, jsp, select, matrix

i get a list from my java code and I would like to create a matrix from this list.
In my jsp I have a select and I would like to display in a table the values of my matrix in relation to value in my select choice

my list in my java

```
<html:select property="immeuble.zone" size="1"  styleId="zone"  styleClass="saisie">
   <html:optionsCollection  property="optionsZone" label="libelle" value="code"/> 
</html:select>
```

my lsit in my jsp

```
List optionsZone = new ArrayList(3);
optionsZone.add(new CodeLibelleBean("1","1"));
optionsZone.add(new CodeLibelleBean("2","2"));
optionsZone.add(new CodeLibelleBean("3","3"));
```

my list in want display

```
HashMap Tarif = new HashMap();
Tarif.put("1","100");
Tarif.put("1","150");
Tarif.put("1","180");
Tarif.put("2","200");
Tarif.put("2","250");
Tarif.put("2","290");
Tarif.put("3","300");
Tarif.put("3","350");
Tarif.put("3","360");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your question, but probably you want to pass your arrays to Javascript and do some operations with them there. If this is the case, you will need to use some Java JSON converter.

Here is a starting point for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library